# Not Found 404 Error when i try to access an express route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

Im running an angular cli generated app with an express js and mongdb server.After running npm start i can access http://localhost:3000 which routes to my homepage,the other links at the navbar works well to control routes eg http://localhost:3000/blackboard which get loaded on clicking the blackboard button .However when i try to type http://localhost:3000/blackboard of http://localhost:3000/home it responds with a Not found.
It also responds with not found when i try to reload the page.
Here is my **app.routing** file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BlackboardComponent } from './blackboard/blackboard.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { BookComponent } from "./book/book.component";
import { BookDetailComponent } from "./book-detail/book-detail.component";
import {BookCreateComponent} from "./book-create/book-create.component";
import {BookEditComponent} from "./book-edit/book-edit.component";


const routes: Routes = [

    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'blackboard', component: BlackboardComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    {  path: 'books',component: BookComponent},
    {  path: 'book-details/:id', component: BookDetailComponent},
    {path: 'book-create',component: BookCreateComponent},
    { path: 'book-edit/:id', component: BookEditComponent},
    ];


    @NgModule({
       imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
       exports: [ RouterModule ]
   })
    export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I run my server through bin/www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('mean-angular6:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}



function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Here is my app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mean-angular6')
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection succesful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

var apiRouter = require('./routes/book');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/mean-angular6')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/mean-angular6')));
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send(err.status);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

"blackboard" is not mentioned in your server-side code, no server-side route matched it so you get 404. You need to add a route to render the home page in this case then Angular can render the client side blackboard route.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the api with postman or curl? We cannot se your api route in the code. In front end you cannot simply reload the page and get the angular route path, but you can add to your router module import a config object to use hash:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```

here the docs https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule